# C# Entitity framework SaveChanges() not working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

After running this code I find no entrys in my database.
I receive no errors from the code.

Does anyone know what I mite be doing wrong ?

```
PeopleEntities1 db = new PeopleEntities1();


            Person roger = new Person() 
            {  
                age = 25,
                firstname = "Roger", 
                lastname = "Rabbit", 
                location = "Canada", 
                job = "freelance", 


            };

            db.AddToPeople(roger);
            db.SaveChanges(true);
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, and if so, can you run SQL Profiler and see what is being executed against the database?

Comment: What is the location of your database? Make sure you are not you're copying it to your output directory everytime you run your code. I  might have had a similar issue with an SQLite database which was copied to the output directory every time I run my application, which made me lose changes I had made during the previous run .

Comment: This is exactly whats happening; I create the database in the project dir, but when it runs its creating the db file again in the bin dir.

Comment: I don't know if I'm supposed to do this, but I have reposted my comment as an answer. Please accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the location of your database? Make sure you are not you're copying it to your output directory everytime you run your code. I might have had a similar issue with an SQLite database which was copied to the output directory every time I run my application, which made me lose changes I had made during the previous run

Comment: I created a standard C# console application in 2010 Express, used the wizards to create a simple sql express db file which gets placed in the project dir, used the wizards to generate an entity data model based on the newly created db, wrote a few lines to test out entity.

Problem is each time I run the application it recreates the DB file in whatever dir the exe is in overwriting itself everytime and completly ignoring the original db file that sits in the project dir

Comment: So what's the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of db.AddToPeople(), try db.People.Add().

Also, wrap a using statement around the db variable to make sure the context and connection get disposed correctly.

This is for EF4 and .NET 4.0.

Assuming you have a list called People setup.

Hope this helps! :)

Here is the code:

```
using (PeopleEntities1 db = new PeopleEntities1())
{


            Person roger = new Person() 
            {  
                age = 25,
                firstname = "Roger", 
                lastname = "Rabbit", 
                location = "Canada", 
                job = "freelance", 


            };

            db.People.Add(roger);
            db.SaveChanges(true);
}
```

Comment: I dont seem to have a db.People.Add() method; BTW I used the wizard to create my entity class from a DB.

Comment: Ok, depending on the pluralization, you may have db.Persons

Comment: The closest thing I have is db.People.AddObject; This gives the same result as db.AddToPeople(), runs with no errors but no entries in DB.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `SaveChanges(true)` is an obsolete method so I wouldn't recommend using it. Have you tried just using `SaveChanges()` ? Like in `db.SaveChanges()`

The closest method to `SaveChanges(boolean)` is `SaveChanges(SaveOptions)` which Persists all updates to the data source with the specified `SaveOptions`.

Comment: Your original comment was probably right - he needs to run profiler, and see *exactly* which DB this is running against.  I'll bet he has his connection strings mixed up