# .SaveChanges not applying changes to database in entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to use the code below to add an entry in the 'UserAlertSubscriptions' table in my db which just links users to alertconfigurations.

The problem is that although i get no errors the entry does not get added to the database.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong. As you can see, I tried ApplyAllChanges, but this made no difference.

```
AlerterDataEntities alerterDataEntities = new AlerterDataEntities()

// get current user
User user = alerterDataEntities.Users.Where(u => u.UserID == 1).ToList<User>()[0];

// get selected alert configuration
AlertConfiguration alertConfiguration =
    alerterDataEntities.AlertConfigurations.Where(a => a.AlertConfigurationID == 3).ToList
        <AlertConfiguration>()[0];

UserAlertSubscription userAlertSubscription = new UserAlertSubscription
{
    User = user,
    AlertConfiguration = alertConfiguration
};

user.UserAlertSubscriptions.Add(userAlertSubscription);
//alerterDataEntities.AcceptAllChanges();
alerterDataEntities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: `var user = alerterDataEntities.Users.First(u => u.UserID == 1)`

Comment: thanks SLaks, that does make it much neater code and i've used 'First' as suggested for user ans alertconfiguration...but alas it still does not savethe relationship to the database.

Comment: That's why it's a comment rather than an answer.  I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: The weird thing is I can see in the debugger after the '.SaveChanges' that there is an extra item in there (in alerterDataEntities.UserAlertSubscriptions). Weirder still i have a textblock in my view bound to the count of the items in that table and when i run it straight after according to the count its there...but in the database it's not. I assume this is some sort of caching...when i look again later, the count of the table is back to what it actually is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All fixed - I found the problem was that the database was being copied to the output directory each time I ran it. So the table I was looking at (the one in the root of my application) was not the one it had added to.

This post solved by @Jean-Lois was where I found the solution:
[C# Entitity framework SaveChanges() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334031/c-entitity-framework-savechanges-not-working)

To solve it I set the database 'Copy to output directory' to 'Do not copy' and put the full file path in the database connection string in the app.config